# Add text at the end of each line

Tags: sed, command-line-interface

I'm on Linux command line and I have file with

```
127.0.0.1
128.0.0.0
121.121.33.111
```

I want

```
127.0.0.1:80
128.0.0.0:80
121.121.33.111:80
```

I remember my colleagues were using sed for that, but after reading sed manual still not clear how to do it on command line?

Answer (score 201):

You could try using something like:

```
sed -n 's/$/:80/' ips.txt > new-ips.txt
```

*Provided that your file format is just as you have described in your question.*

The `s///` substitution command matches (*finds*) the end of each line in your file (using the `$` character) and then appends (*replaces*) the `:80` to the end of each line.  The `ips.txt` file is your input file... and `new-ips.txt` is your newly-created file (*the final result of your changes.*)

---

Also, if you have a list of IP numbers that happen to have port numbers attached already, (as noted by [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143917/vlad) and as given by [aragaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390363/aragaer),) you could try using something like:

```
sed '/:[0-9]*$/ ! s/$/:80/' ips.txt > new-ips.txt
```

So, for example, if your input file looked something like this *(note the `:80`)*:

```
127.0.0.1
128.0.0.0:80
121.121.33.111
```

The final result would look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1:80
128.0.0.0:80
121.121.33.111:80
```

Comment: @Vlad Yes; but according to the OPs given example input... there shouldn't be any port numbers in the list of IPs. :)  Even if there were... the OP could just run another sed `s///` beforehand to take out any port numbers at the end of each line.

Comment: Ok, just clarifying... Maybe there should be a condition to exclude lines where a port already exists.

Comment: `sed '/:[0-9]*$/ ! s/$/:80/'`

Comment: @aragaer Did you want to post that as another answer?  Or do you mind if I include that (with attribution) in this answer?  It may be something the OP needs in the future, at least...

Comment: Add it to your own answer. The suggestion to exclude lines with ports is already here in comments, I just wrote the exact command.

Comment: If the file has CRLF terminators, the ``:80`` will be added to the beginning of the following line. Use ``dos2unix`` on the file first if necessary.

Comment: is the `-n` necessary?  probably not for most users.

Answer (score 75):

## Concise version of the *sed* command:

```
sed -i s/$/:80/ file.txt
```

## Explanation:

- `sed` **s**tream **ed**itor
- `-i` **i**n-place (edit file in place)
- `s` **s**ubstitution command
- `/replacement_from_reg_exp/replacement_to_text/` statement
- `$` matches the end of line (*replacement_from_reg_exp*)
- `:80` text you want to add at the end of every line (*replacement_to_text*)
- `file.txt` the file name

## How can this be achieved without modifying the original file?

If you want to leave the original file unchanged and have the results in another file, then give up `-i` option and add  the redirection (`>`) to another file:

```
sed s/$/:80/ file.txt > another_file.txt
```

Comment: Shell newbie here. How do we provide a variable name instead of :80 in this statment. The below statements didnt work for me. Thanks in advance.
sed -i s/$/$value/ file.txt
sed -i s/$/${value}/file.txt

Comment: Hi @NikethKovin, both `sed -i s/$/$value/ file.txt` and `sed -i s/$/${value}/ file.txt` options  work very well in my case.

Answer (score 21):

```
sed 's/.*/&:80/'  abcd.txt >abcde.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this easy to understand solution. I am using a modified version of this. if line does not end with `/`, add `/`. `sed 's#[^/]$#&/#' fix-url.txt > fix.txt`.

Comment: regex explenation: search for any sequence of characters (.*) in each line and replace it with itself (&) followed by :80.

Answer (score 17):

If you'd like to add text at the end of each line in-place (in the same file), you can use `-i` parameter, for example:

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/$/:80/' foo.txt
```

However `-i` option is non-standard Unix extension and may not be available on all operating systems.

So you can consider using [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) (which is equivalent to `vi -e`/`vim -e`):

```
ex +"%s/$/:80/g" -cwq foo.txt
```

which will add `:80` to each line, but sometimes it can append it to blank lines.

So better method is to check if the line actually contain any number, and then append it, for example:

```
ex  +"g/[0-9]/s/$/:80/g" -cwq foo.txt
```

If the file has more complex format, consider using proper regex, instead of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can also achieve this using the backreference technique

   ```
   sed -i.bak 's/\(.*\)/\1:80/' foo.txt
   ```
2. You can also use with awk like this

   ```
   awk '{print $0":80"}' foo.txt > tmp && mv tmp foo.txt
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Using a text editor, check for `^M` (control-M, or carriage return) at the end of each line. You will need to remove them first, then append the additional text at the end of the line.

```
sed -i 's|^M||g' ips.txt
sed -i 's|$|:80|g' ips.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

sed -i 's/$/,/g' foo.txt

I do this quite often to add a comma to the end of an output so I can just easily copy and paste it into a Python(or your fav lang) array

Comment: Worked for me to edit a bunch of CSV's to which I added a column and therefore needed an extra separator at the end of each line. Has the added benefit of adding it to the last line, while replacing linebreaks (\r) doesn't achieve that - grep -RiIl '\r' | xargs sed -i 's/\r/;\r/g'