# Insert part of the file name in headers of the file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk, file-rename

I would like to insert in my file a part of the title of the file.

the file title is

> GeneName_something.fas.

And my files have this format:

> '>Speciesa
>   atgaatatagatata
>   '>Speciesb
>   atagtagctatgat

I would like to insert the Gene name after the Species name. output will be:

> '>Speciesa-GeneName
>   atgaatatagatata
>   '>Speciesb-GeneName
>   atagtagctatgat

I would like to use bash with maybe awk or sed and run it as a loop in my folder.
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add text at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978504/add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk (`BEGINFILE` could be replaced with `FNR==1` but I'm using `-i inplace`):

```
$ awk '
  BEGINFILE { split(FILENAME,f,"_") }  # split filename on _
  /^\47/ { $0=$0"-"f[1] }              # add to quote-starting records
  1' GeneName_something.fas            # output
'>Speciesa-GeneName
atgaatatagatata
'>Speciesb-GeneName
atagtagctatgat
```

This version outputs changed data to stdout but you can use `awk -i inplace` for inplace editing the file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)).

**Notice**, that there is no check for the filename that the `GeneName` actually exists. If it doesn't exist, a `-` will be added anyway.

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried but it is not working. Can you explain the part /^\47/ please? what is it 47? Maybe can explain why this is not working. In fact my line start like this >Speciesa. there is no ' (dont know how to show it correctly on stackoverflow.

Comment: `\47` is the single quote `'` as in your question lines start with it. If they start with something else (`>` perhaps) replace `\47` with `>`.

Comment: yes sorry my bad. Work now. At least now i know \47 = '

Comment: If you stick with awk, you'll need that info.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk`s could also help you on same.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk 'FNR==1{val=FILENAME;sub(/_.*/,"",val)} />Species/{$0=$0"-"val;} 1' GeneName_something.fas
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk 'FNR==1{val=FILENAME;sub(/_.*/,"",val)} />Species/{print $0"-"val;next} 1' GeneName_something.fas
```