# How to merge multiple files in order and append filename at the end in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have multiple files like this:

```
BOB_1.brother_bob12.txt
BOB_2.brother_bob12.txt
..
BOB_35.brother_bob12.txt
```

How to join these files in order from `{1..36}` and append filename at the end of each row? I have tried:

```
for i in *.txt; do sed 's/$/ '"$i"'/' $i; done > outfile #joins but not in order
cat $(for((i=1;i<38;i++)); do echo -n "BOB_${i}.brother_bob12.txt "; done) # joins in order but no filename at the end
```

file sample:

```
1 345 378 1 3 4 5 C T
1 456 789 -1 2 3 4 A T
```

Comment: :D `append filename at the end of each row?` so like you want the first line in output to be `1 345 378 1 3 4 5 C T BOB_1.brother_bob12.txt` ?

Comment: exactly what I want to do :)

Comment: `joins but not in order` - it would be in order, but in order like `1` `10` `11` ... `19`  `2` `20` `21` ... etc., because like `2_` is sorted after `10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do `cat $(....)`. You may just:

```
for ((i=1;i<38;i++)); do 
     f="BOB_${i}.brother_bob12.txt"
     sed "s/$/ $f/" "$f"
done
```

You may also do:

```
printf "%s\n" bob.txt BOB_{1..38}.brother_bob12.txt |
     xargs -d'\n' -i sed 's/$/ {}/' '{}'
```

Comment: could you please explain so that I can modify if needed... for example if I want to add a file named differently. Thnaks!

Comment: Well, there is `'s/$/ '"$i"'/' $i` in your code also, it does the same thing. Just the loop is different. Maybe look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978504/add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line and read some sed introduction. For learning regex, I recommend regex crosswords, they are amazing and fun. Which part exactly you do not understand? To add a filename differently , modify the `"s/$/ $f/"` command, but for anything more complicated `awk` may be more suitable.

Comment: Is it posssible to add a file with different name before all bob file and how?

Comment: What name exactly? You may edit with `s/$/ different_name_before_bob_BOB_${i}/`.

Comment: it is file named bob.txt that should go at the beginning before all other files..

Comment: Soooo just add before it `sed "s/$/ bob.txt/" "bob.txt"`?

Comment: Please be specific. If your file is not `bob.txt` but `/the/path/to/bob.txt` then you will get such error. Consider using a different `s` separator, like `s~pattern~replacement~` (any character may be used) like `s@$@ bob.txt@`. For more information, research `sed` `s` command.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```sh
for i in {1..36}; do
   fn="BOB_${i}.brother_bob12.txt"
   [[ -f $fn ]] && awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $0, FILENAME}' "$fn"
done > output
```

Note that it will insert `FILENAME` as the last field in every record. If this is not what you want then show your expected output in question.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed -n 'p;F' BOB_{1..36}.brother_bob12.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' >newFile
```

Used 2 invocations of sed, the first to append the file name after each line of each file. The second to replace the newline between each 2 lines by a space.