# How can I replace "^M" with ",1" at the end using sed on Mac OS?

Tags: sed

How can I add ",1" at the end of each of the lines using sed?
The file I am using is like this;

```
A
B
C
```

I tried this;

```
sed 's/$/,1/' alphabets.txt > alphabets1.txt
```

and got this;

```
A
,1
B
,1
C
,1
```

but what I want is this;

```
A,1
B,1
C,1
```

When I tried the best answer from "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978504/add-text-at-the-end-of-each-line", I got a blank page.

```
sed -n 's/$/,1/' alphabets.txt > alphabets2.txt
```

I found out that there's ^M at the end using cat -vt file. How can I delete it and change it to ",1"?

Comment: Looks like you have DOS line ending in your input file. Can you show output of `cat -A file`

Comment: When I typed 
`$ cat -A alphabets.txt`, I got this;
`cat: illegal option -- A
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]`

Comment: Try `cat -vt file`

Comment: Thank you!! I had ^M at the end of each line!!

Comment: How can I delete those "^M" and insert ",1" instead?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/\r?$/,1/' file`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference when I typed that command... there's still "^M" at the end, and there's no ",1" either...

Comment: What is your `sed` version? What OS you are on?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac `sed` is BSD sed. You may try this command on a file *optionally* ending with `\r` to remove `\r` and append `1` in the end:

```sh
sed -E $'s/\\\r?$/,1/'

A,1
B,1
C,1
```

Make sure you shell is `bash` while running this.

You may also use:

```
sed -E 's/'$'\r''?$/,1/' file
```

`$'\r'` is a BASH string to match `\r` and `?` after this makes it optional.

Please note that this sed command will also run fine on `gnu sed`.

Comment: You are a genius!!! Thank you so much for your amazing answer, it has worked, and you have saved my day!!! Thank you again!!