# SED - using $ inserts string at beginning of line instead of end

Tags: sed

I am not getting expected results from sed 's/$/2021-07-21/' demotoytable.csv

Before the command the top 3 lines look like:

```
urlhm|main_code|description|taxable|itemnum|xtras
t3mr.com/guitar/qrc/G19RTE000000753|G19RTE0000007530|Promo_labor_day_006|Consignment|7522831|bag
t3mr.com/guitar/qrc/G19RTE000000753|G19RTE0000007530|Promo_labor_day_006|Consignment|7522835|box
t3mr.com/guitar/qrc/G19RTE000000753|G19RTE0000007530|Promo_labor_day_006|Consignment|7522839|case
```

But after running the command `sed 's/$/|2021-07-21/' demotoytable.csv`
I get this result:

```
|2021-07-21code|description|taxable|itemnum|xtras
|2021-07-21itar/qrc/G19RTE000000753|G19RTE0000007530|Promo_labor_day_006|Consignment|7522831|bag
|2021-07-21itar/qrc/G19RTE000000753|G19RTE0000007530|Promo_labor_day_006|Consignment|7522835|box
|2021-07-21itar/qrc/G19RTE000000753|G19RTE0000007530|Promo_labor_day_006|Consignment|7522839|case
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, or better yet how to fix?  I want each line to end w "|2021-07-21",  not begin with it.   On a Mac Pro running Big Sur

Thanks

Comment: SUGGESTION: Try "&": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296705/using-sed-with-ampersand.  SEE ALSO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154091/421195

Comment: It is because your input file is ending with carriage return or `\r`. Remove that using `tr` or `sed` first.

Answer (score 1):

Remove carriage returns  and then add the texts you wish to add:

```sh
sed 's/\r$//; s/$/|2021-07-21/' demotoytable.csv
```

`s/\r$//` removes carriage returns at the end of lines, `s/$/|2021-07-21/` in its turn appends the value of your choice at the end of lines.